# react-native-maps is blank on ios

Tags: react-native

*i just started with react-native-maps when i run my code i am getting blank screen on my iPhone6 Plus simulator.*

*I gone through [Blank Map #118](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/issues/118) issue. i excuted `npm link`command but still i am facing the same issue.*

*below is my code:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 AppRegistry,
 StyleSheet,
 View,
} from 'react-native';
import Api from './src/api';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
map: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
},
});

class weather extends Component {

constructor() {
  super();
}

render() {
  return (
  <MapView
    style={ styles.map }
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
  );
 }
}
```

*Below is the out put when i run `npm link`*

```
Ashok$ npm link
weather@0.0.1 /Users/Ashok/weather
└── react-native-maps@0.7.1 

/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/weather -> /Users/Ashok/weather
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Make sure you run:**

- `react-native link`
- `react-native run-ios`

**2 - Make sure the google_api_key is correct and enabled.**

Reference: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Answer (score 0):

Try again to install from scratch but do not give you react-native link if not just after you've dragged your folders from node_modules, created your podfile and pod install.