# React-native-map shows empty map when zooming in for some locations

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

It may sound very silly but RNM framework behaves differently for different locations. The react-native-map works great for California and some other states. But when I try to search for a location in NY or Michigan (and some other places) it just acts weird:

1. The map zooms in to a random empty location.
2. When you try to zoom in it zooms out automatically.
3. Double tap zooms out of the map rather than zooming in.

> ```
> react: 16.6
> react-native: 0.57.7
> react-native-maps: 0.25.0
> ```

[image]

Note: I am running it on iOS with default provider (Apple Maps).

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784644/react-native-maps-is-blank-on-ios?